# Error "layer not accessible" in creating ArcGIS Operation Dashboard and problem in adding feature layer

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, operations-dashboard

I am currently working on an operational dashboard.

Apparently, I wasn't able to create a dashboard from a web map due to an error message `layer not accessible`. I also failed in uploading a feature layer. I observed that the checkbox stating `Publish this file as a hosted layer` is missing every time I tried to add a new item.

I hope somebody can explain why the layer is not accessible and the missing feature of publishing a hosted layer when adding an item in my content.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a publisher in order to host a layer, see if your administrator can do this for you.